# If a person has broken their fast for a valid reason, should they eat differently?

Tags: sawm, food

For whatever reason,  this person has to break their fast.

Should they eat less or differently?  Does it change is it is voluntary or obligatory fasting?

Comment: What do you mean by _eat differently_?

Comment: @ozbeck, anything that is different to their normal non-fasting eating patterns. So eating more or less,  eating at different times, eating in seclusion. Anything.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "eating differently". Why do you think they should? And what is the relevance for the "kind" of fast? Maybe i miss the point of your question :-\ Could you give an example or so? It seems to me that you are looking for an advise for such a case: I mean there's no general hint, as for example a diabetic may have an other time schedule than a person who has a temporary illness. IMO -in that situation- at least one should eat when he/she gets hungry or thirsty.

Answer (score -1):

No he shouldn't , and it doesn't depend on obligatory or voluntary. But if it is during daytime of Ramadan , and if he can , he may not eat or drink in public.